# How to do streaming using wowza mediaserver

Tags: streaming, wowza, wowza-transcoder

i have another question for multiple streaming through which 
PC1(in LAN) run on my wowza media server and after that same live video is to be pass to PC2(in LAN).
PC2 to whom i gave url to play the video

Answer (score 0):

(Hopefully that will not sound rude) I suggest to improve your english and question in general, because it sounds really foggy.

From what i understand, you need to setup PC1 as distro and PC2 as edge.
Stream type "liverepeater-edge" should help you.

Best regards!